# Is there any way to determine sub-protocol conformance for instance conforming to generic protocol in Swift 2 (at runtime or during compilation)?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, type-erasure

I'm porting Java library to Swift 2.0 and have some troubles with generics.

I have following protocol hierarchy:

```
public protocol Graph {
    typealias V: Hashable
    typealias E: Hashable

    func getAllEdges(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V) -> Set<E>?
    func getEdge(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V) -> E?
    func getEdgeFactory() -> EdgeFactory<V, E>?
    func addEdge(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V) -> E?
    func addEdge(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V, e: E) -> Bool
    func addVertex(v: V) -> Bool
    func containsEdge(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V) -> Bool
    func containsEdge(e: E) -> Bool
    func containsVertex(v: V) -> Bool
    func edgeSet() -> Set<E>
    func edgesOf(v: V) -> Set<E>
    func removeAllEdges<T: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element == E>(edges: T) -> Bool
    func removeAllEdges(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V) -> Set<E>?
    func removeAllVertices<T: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element == V>(vertices: T) -> Bool
    func removeEdge(sourceVertex: V, targetVertex: V)
    func removeEdge(e: E) -> Bool
    func removeVertex(v: V) -> Bool
    func vertexSet() -> Set<V>
    func getEdgeSource(e: E) -> V
    func getEdgeTarget(e: E) -> V
    func getEdgeWeight(e: E) -> Double
}

public protocol DirectedGraph: Graph {
    func inDegreeOf(vertex: V) -> Int
    func incomingEdgesOf(vertex: V) -> Set<E>
    func outDegreeOf(vertex: V) -> Int
    func outgoingEdgesOf(vertex: V) -> Set<E>
}

public protocol UndirectedGraph: Graph {    
    func degreeOf(vertex: V) -> Int
}
```

And here's definition of class which causes trouble:

```
public class CrossComponentIterator
    <V: Hashable, E: Hashable, D, G: Graph
        where G.V == V, G.E == E>
    : AbstractGraphIterator<V, E>
```

Namely, it has method which should init one of its variables based on actual type of graph passed - DirectedGraph or UndirectedGraph.

I've tried solving this by declaring multiple versions of the function which does this:

```
func createGraphSpecifics<DG: Graph where DG: DirectedGraph, DG.V == V, DG.E == E>(graph: DG)
    -> CrossComponentIteratorSpecifics<V, E>
{
    return DirectedSpecifics<V, E, DG>(graph: graph)
}

func createGraphSpecifics<UG: Graph where UG: UndirectedGraph, UG.V == V, UG.E == E>(graph: UG)
    -> CrossComponentIteratorSpecifics<V, E>
{
    return UndirectedSpecifics<V, E, UG>(graph: graph)
}

func createGraphSpecifics<GG: Graph where GG.V == V, GG.E == E>(graph: GG)
    -> CrossComponentIteratorSpecifics<V, E>
{
    fatalError("Unknown graph type instance")
}
```

But unfortunately, only last version of function is called for any instance of graph (even if it conforms to "DirectedGraph" or "UndirectedGraph")

And I know, that probably I can solve this problem by converting protocols DirectedGraph and UndirectedGraph to abstract classes 
(by that I mean classes with fatalError() in each declared function since Swift doesn't support abstract classes de jure).

But maybe there is another, more elegant and Swifty solution?

In Java this is trivial - conformance to interface is checked at runtime:

```
if (g instanceof DirectedGraph<?, ?>) {
    return new DirectedSpecifics<V, E>((DirectedGraph<V, E>) g);
} else {
    return new UndirectedSpecifics<V, E>(g);
}
```

**Edit** here's minimal code for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
protocol P {
    // This typealias makes impossible to use 'P'
    // (or its descendants) as a type.
    // It can be used only as generic constraint.
    typealias A

    // myfunc is needed for compiler to infer 'A'
    func myfunc(a: A)
}
protocol P1:P {
    func p1specific(a: A)
}
protocol P2:P {
    func p2specific(a: A)
}

struct S<T:P> {
    init(t: T) {
        // TODO: check if 't' conforms to 'P1', 'P2', both or neither
    }
}

// Examples of concrete implementations of 'P1' and 'P2'
struct S1<X>:P1{
    func myfunc(a: X) {}
    func p1specific(a: X) {}
}
struct S2<X>:P2{
    func myfunc(a: X) {}
    func p2specific(a: X) {}
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution? is yes, please share it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to determine sub-protocol conformance for instance
>   conforming to generic protocol in Swift 2 (at runtime or during
>   compilation)?

**Yes.**

Here's my trick for achieving type erasure, hence allowing one to utilize the runtime. Observe `_P`:

```
protocol _P {
    static var _A: Any.Type { get }
    func _myfunc(_a: Any) -> Void?
}

extension _P where Self: P {

    static var _A: Any.Type {
        return A.self
    }

    func _myfunc(_a: Any) -> Void? {
        return (_a as? A).map(myfunc)
    }
}

protocol P {
    typealias A

    func myfunc(a: A)
}

protocol _P1:_P {
    func _p1specific(_a: Any) -> Void?
}

extension _P1 where Self: P1 {
    func _p1specific(_a: Any) -> Void? {
        return (_a as? A).map(p1specific)
    }
}

protocol P1:_P1, P {
    func p1specific(a: A)
}

protocol _P2:_P {
    func _p2specific(_a: Any) -> Void?
}

extension _P2 where Self: P2 {
    func _p2specific(_a: Any) -> Void? {
        return (_a as? A).map(p2specific)
    }
}

protocol P2:_P2, P {
    func p2specific(a: A)
}
```

You can now determine whether a value conforms to `P1` or `P2`, and force cast accordingly. Additionally, the generic parameter `A` is now available via the opaque `Any.Type`.

`(x as? _P1) != nil ? true : false`

Comment: @user3441734: Your downvote is unjustified. Please take a look at my edit, hopefully this clarifies any doubts.

Comment: @user3441734: But I'm not testing whether they conform to `Any.Type`. I'm testing whether type `A` conforms to `_P1` in `(x._A as? _P1.Type) != nil ? true : false`.

Comment: `_A` is of type `Any.Type`. I'm testing this opaque type for conformance to `_P1.Type`.

Comment: please, show me an example how to use it in 'minimal code for what OP is trying to achieve'

Comment: @user3441734: Your lack of knowledge appalls me. But, here you go: https://gist.github.com/vmanot/a764f32290ab83550f42

Comment: @VatsalManot thank you, this is very close to what I'm trying to achieve. Do you have any ideas how to call `p1specific `/`p2specific` methods from init in `struct S<T:P> { init(t: T) }`? We still can't cast to `P1`/`P2` directly because of the typealias parameter.

Comment: @PeterProkop: Look at how I made `myfunc` available in the opaque `_P` protocol. You can apply this technique to `_P1` and `_P1` respectively.

Comment: @VatsalManot i left you some notes to your gist

Comment: @user3441734: And I've read them. You continue to demonstrate a remarkable failure in understanding my answer. I suggest you either read it carefully, or stop bothering me :)

Comment: :-) you can continue to demonstrate what do you want, without any help to OP

Answer (score -1):

```
import XCPlayground
import Foundation

protocol P {}
protocol P1:P {}
protocol P2:P {}

struct S1:P1{}
struct S2:P2{}

struct S<T:P> {
    var p1: P1?
    var p2: P2?

    init(t: T) {
        p1 = t as? P1
        p2 = t as? P2
    }
}

let p1 = S1()
let p2 = S2()
let s1 = S(t: p1)
let s2 = S(t: p2)

dump(s1)
dump(s2)
/*
▿ S<S1>
  ▿ p1: S1
    - Some: S1
  - p2: nil
▿ S<S2>
  - p1: nil
  ▿ p2: S2
    - Some: S2
*/
```

use

```
g is Type             // trur or false
```

and

```
let v2 = v1 as? Type   // v2 = v2 or nil
```

in swift 
update

```
protocol P {
    typealias A
}
protocol P1:P {}
protocol P2:P {}

struct S1:P1{
    typealias A = Int
}
struct S2:P2{
    typealias A = Double
}

struct S<T:P> {
    var p1: S1?
    var p2: S2?

    init(t: T) {
        p1 = t as? S1
        p2 = t as? S2
    }
}

let p1 = S1()
let p2 = S2()
let s1 = S(t: p1)
let s2 = S(t: p2)
```

.....

```
protocol P {
    // This typealias makes impossible to use 'P'
    // (or its descendants) as a type.
    // It can be used only as generic constraint.
    typealias A

    // myfunc is needed for compiler to infer 'A'
    func myfunc(a: A)
}
protocol P1:P {}
protocol P2:P {}

// aka 'abstract' conforming to P1
struct S1:P1{
    typealias A = AnyObject
    func myfunc(a: A) {}
}
// aka 'abstract' conforming to P2
struct S2:P2{
    typealias A = Int
    func myfunc(a: A) {}
}
// generic struct with type conforming to P
struct S<T:P> {
    init(t: T) {
        // TODO: check if 't' conforms to 'P1', 'P2', both or neither
        if t is S1 {
            print("t conforms to P1, because it is type S1")
        }
        if t is S2 {
            print("t conforms to P2, besause it is type S2")
        }
    }
}

let s1 = S(t: S1()) // t conforms to P1, because it is type S1
let s2 = S(t: S2()) // t conforms to P2, besause it is type S2

// WARNING !!!!!!
// var s = s1
// s = s2   // error: cannot assign value of type 'S<S2>' to type 'S<S1>'
```

Comment: Your code works, but if you add "typealias A" to "protocol P" (i.e. make it similar to generic interface in Java) you'll get following error during compilation: "error: protocol 'P1' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements". I.e. you can't use "as?" because P1 and P2 is not a type, but generic constraint.

Comment: what is the trouble? give me a small  and simplified example code. concept of abstract class is not working in swift.

Comment: Sure. I've added minimal example to the question.

Comment: I think, unfortunately, converting to concrete struct/class implementation  (`p1 = t as? S1`) is not very useful, because there can be a lot of concrete implementations for both P1 and P2 (and some of them can be generic).

Comment: @PeterProkop there is no way for direct 'translation' between java and swift. you have to take it in account ...

Comment: @user3441734: Not an excuse. What the OP asks _is_ possible if one applies a little extra thought into the matter.